# How would I compare one value to multiple?

Tags: python, list, logic

```
past_move = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
o_win = ["O", "O", "O"]
if past_move[:3] == o_win or past_move[3:5] == o_win or past_move[6:8] == o_win or past_move[:8:3] == o_win or past_move[1::3] == o_win or past_move[2::3] == o_win or past_move[0::4] == o_win or past_move[2:8:2] == o_win:
```

This is my current code but I don't like it because if I want to add a different set of variable to compare it to it would be a long peice of code running slowly.
`past_move` has "Os" being added to different locations in the string and I need to check for a pattern in the pattern of "Os"

Is there a more efficient way of writing this `if` statement out?

Comment: could you combine all the "past moves" into one temp list and then just say `o_win in temp_list`?

Comment: Is `past_move` supposed to be a grid for tic tac toe? You might want to rethink how you approach this, perhaps a 3x3 matrix instead of one list.  It'll make it much simpler to compare, otherwise you're pretty much stuck with your multiple `if` statements.

Comment: Did you mean `3:6`, `6:9`, etc? Also, what about `1:4`, `2:5`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` operator for a *list of your compared values*:

```
if o_win in [past_move[:3], past_move[3:5], past_move[6:8],
             past_move[:8:3], past_move[1::3], past_move[2::3],
             past_move[0::4], past_move[2:8:2]]:
```